# Processing result sets of queries with package 'rmongodb'

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

How would you go about processing a result set (**length > 1**) of a MongoDB query when using the [rmongodb](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html) package and when your final object should be a `list`?

I try to avoid R-typical "pass-by-value" copying inefficiencies which occur when simply appending the `list` object while stepping through the result set. But in order to do that, I guess I would need to know how many "records" the query returned in total, don't I? That way I could span an empty list and just have that filled when stepping through the result set - or even better, I could use `lapply()` and the like.

Here's a little example

### Example Content

The example is taken from the [MongoDB Website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying+and+nulls) and implemented via [rmongodb](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html)

```
mongo <- mongo.create(db="test")
ns <- "test.foo"
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "x", 1)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "y", 1)
x.1 <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "x", 2)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "y", "string")
x.2 <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "x", 3)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "y", NULL)
x.3 <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "x", 4)
x.4 <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)

mongo.insert.batch(mongo, ns, list(x.1, x.2, x.3, x.4))
```

### Query

```
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns, query=list(y=NULL))

# Alternatively
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "y", NULL)
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns, query)
```

### Processing Query Result

That's the best that I could come up with:

```
out <- NULL
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor)) {
    out <- c(out, list(mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))))
}
out
```

Yet what I'm looking for is something like `as.list(cursor)` or something like this:

```
# Say I could find out the length of the result set:
cursor.length <- length(cursor
out <- lapply(cursor.length, function(x) {
    mongo.cursor.value(cursor[[x]])
)}

# Alternative:
out <- vector("list", cursor.length)
for (x in 1:cursor.length) {
    out[[x]] <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor[[x]])
)}
```

Is this possible? Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with C/C++ pointer which I think are used by the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered this question in the FAQ on rmongodb at http://cnub.org/rmongodb.ashx#FAQ
This shows how to get arrays, lists and data frames from your queries.